# R Parallel Processing, cannot complete all the task

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have 941 URLs to **scrape** and I tried to do parallel processing using R on Linux to do this task. Funny, not all URLs **scraped** but when I tried use non parallel programming, all URL scraped. Below are the chunk of my script on the **scraping** section:

Parallel :

```
foreach(a=1:ntasks) %dopar% {

     #script to scrape URL

}
```

Non Parallel

```
for(a in 1:ntasks) {

    #script to scrape URL

 }
```

Did I miss something?

Please advise

Comment: Have you used a library to initialize the number of cpus that you want to use? what library?

Comment: yes of course, otherwise it would not run. I use below libraries:

library(doMC)
library(foreach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not continue this task and consider the condition as a natural condition